# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when adding polyline to map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)` error when trying to add a polyline to my Google Map.

If I comment out the line `polyline.map = mapView`, everything works just fine.

Given the vagueness of the error, I'm unsure as to the root cause, or whether it's just because the Simulator I'm running the app on is so slow. I've not been able to test it on a real device yet.

```
let path = GMSMutablePath()
for coordinate in route.polyline.geoJsonLinestring.coordinates {
    path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate[1], longitude: coordinate[0]))
    print(coordinate)
}

let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path)
let cameraUpdate = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 16)

DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
    let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    polyline.strokeColor = UIColor(named: "AccentColor")!
    polyline.strokeWidth = 5
    polyline.map = mapView
    
    mapView?.moveCamera(cameraUpdate)
}
```

The crash doesn't necessarily happen straight away - when I zoom the map out after adding the polyline, that's when it seems to crash most often.

Update:

I tried changing the `GPU Frame Capture` setting in `Edit Scheme` but it had no impact.

I also created a simple view with a map and a hardcoded 2 coordinate polyline, and it still crashes. This is literally it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    var coordinates = [
        [-2.9287110999999997, 54.8929171],
        [-2.8932368, 54.8968314],
    ]
    let path = GMSMutablePath()
    for coordinate in coordinates {
        path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate[1], longitude: coordinate[0]))
    }
    
    let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path)
    let cameraUpdate = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 16)
    let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    polyline.strokeColor = UIColor(named: "AccentColor")!
    polyline.strokeWidth = 10
    polyline.map = mapView
    
    mapView?.moveCamera(cameraUpdate)
}
```

Crashes after the map fully loads, which takes about a minute.

The performance of Google Maps in the simulator in general is terrible. The map view always seems to take >1 minute to fully load (grey view with Google logo then the tiles eventually appear).

Comment: Will this help? https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/exc-bad-access-crash/

Comment: @Yrll I have been through that. Still haven't really managed to narrow the problem down unfortunately. Similar issues sometimes suggest it's an Apple bug, again complicating things.

Comment: Do you have stack traces for this? You can file a bug to the [public issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker) to let Google Maps Engineers investigate this further if it is related to the SDK or not. Or file a bug to apple if this is indeed an apple bug.

Comment: Probably will have to. They're so obtuse. I stripped everything back to just the map and a hardcoded 2 coordinate polyline and it still crashes. Reinstalled the SDK, reset the simulator... still no luck. I miss developing for Android.

Comment: Why do people vote to close without specifying why? It seems like a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug, as I can reproduce it with the `maps-sdk-for-ios-samples` demo app. I've filed a bug report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/323404687